# How to query in SQLite using BETWEEN and DOUBLE values?

Tags: android, sqlite, gps

Hi everyone I have to query from db using BETWEEN on two DOUBLE values

This is my Table:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Task ("
                    + "id smallint(6) NOT NULL,"
                    + "project_id smallint(6) NOT NULL," 
                    + "add_date varchar(15) NOT NULL,"
                    + "geo_lat double NOT NULL,"
                    + "geo_long double NOT NULL,"
                    + "additional_info TEXT NULL" + ");");
```

I want to show all nearest Tasks and my current QUERY is:

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE geo_lat BETWEEN " + lat_top + " AND " + lat_bot + " AND geo_long" + " BETWEEN " + long_top + " AND " + long_bot
```

I dont know is it wrong or not, i have found it somewhere in this forum. This query returns me nothing... How it shoud be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of the top and bottom in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE geo_lat 
     BETWEEN " + lat_bot+ " AND " + lat_top + " 
     AND geo_long" + " 
     BETWEEN " + long_bot + " AND " + long_top
```

Your sample filled query would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM TASK WHERE 
( GEO_LAT BETWEEN 12.01 AND 12.50 ) 
AND
(GEO_LONG BETWEEN 81.10 AND 91.20)
```

Answer (score 3):

`a BETWEEN b AND c` is the same as `a >= b AND a <= c`.

So you have to ensure that the smaller of the two values comes before the `AND`.

Comment: This was frustrating to realize, especially when dealing with longitudes and latitudes. Easy fix with `Math.min(min,max), Math.max(min,max)`